# AFNetworking 2.0 Get JSON from code 400 in failure block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for a `POST` request. Now I'm deliberately entering incorrect information to handle a `400` error code. Now, the web service actually returns a `JSON` with a message explaining to the user what they've done wrong. I would very much like to get this `JSON` to display the message in a `UIAlertView`. However, the failure block of:

```
[operationManager POST:ServerURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: Status Code: %d", operation.response.statusCode);
}
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Failed: Status Code: %d", operation.response.statusCode);
 }];
```

doesn't pass down a responseObject like the one in the success block. So does anyone know how I can access the JSON returned by the Web Service with the 400 error? The `NSError *error` simply gives me `Request failed: bad request (400)` and not the JSON returned.

Any help would be appreciated,
Mike

Comment: I am getting the same response, did you get any solution to the problem?

Comment: This answer worked for me, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24645209/646553

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the code for `- responseObject`, it appears that an HTTP error prevents it from being populated. You can grab the `responseData` directly and parse it yourself, but I would say this is either a bug or a good enhancement request. (It looks like `- responseObject` probably should be checking `self.responseSerializationError`, not `self.error`, when deciding if it should try to build a response object.)

Comment: Hey Jesse thanks for the great answer, very detailed. I'll probably have snoop around myself now and see if I can't make a little change, but we'll see.

Comment: Is there any way it would return the server response in json. yet!

Comment: You have probably got around this but you can get the responseObject from the AFHTTPRequestOperation object in the failure block

Comment: @tbag The problem is that the responseObject is nil in the failure block.

Comment: There are many issues on Github about this, but Matt says it will break API design

Answer (score 5):

You can do either of these solutions

1) Set the `acceptableStatusCodes` to accept your 400 statusCode, and you handle in the success block

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:400];
```

2) Create a custom ResponseSerializer, like this [JSONResponseSerializerWithData](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/239), to insert the responseObject into the NSError userInfo, and handle in the failure block

**Pro tip**: AFNetworking is opensource, just take a look at AFHTTPRequestOperation for methods

```
setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:

responseObject

error
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worded for me:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", BASE_URL,methodName];



    [manager POST:URLString parameters:requestDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        [myDelegate StopIndicator];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [myDelegate StopIndicator];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem in AFNetworking, as instead of using

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                parameters:(id)parameters
                  progress:(void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))uploadProgress
                   success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull, id _Nullable))success
                   failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable, NSError * _Nonnull))failure
```

Please try to use that one :-

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                parameters:(id)parameters
 constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                  progress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))uploadProgress
                   success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                   failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
```

thanks,