# UIAlertView for when fetching JSON fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uialertview

I'm trying to get this UIAlertView to run when fetching the JSON data fails, but i can't seem to get it to work.  I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how to do it or point me in the right direction!

Comment: Fails how? Provide more details about what is actually happening versus what you expect to happen.

Comment: Also note that you must perform UI work on the main thread.

Comment: check response object header. In that check the status code.200 or 400 or whatever and act accordingly

Comment: If it fails to get the contents of the JSON (Not fundamental failures which are already accounted for by the completion/failure blocks). The self.jobs != nil is not doing anything. When i comment out the line "self.jobs  = (NSArray *)responseObject;" , it works, but when i leave it in there and it fails, nothing happens.

Comment: #Jgreen727. Check your responseObject data type. Is it NSArray or anything else? like NSDictionary? May typeCasting getting failed.

Comment: I updated it with more code if that helps you guys

Comment: #Jgreen727, Can you add you json response too in your question.

Comment: Sometimes it fails and just returns a blank tableview, which i assume is it failing to retrieve the JSON data. That's what I'm trying to check for with the if self.jobs = nil block.  The only issue is that is not working.

Comment: What do you mean my json response?

Comment: What you are getting in responseObject?

Comment: are you getting sometimes this..    [ ]    only?

Comment: how would i check what I'm getting?

Comment: Do NSLog for it and print it in console. NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

Comment: I ran this service with some garbage values and got this in response  [ ]  Is this the case with you too?

Comment: on failure i get [9853:2285091] ( )

Comment: Try to check NSError of failure block. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19102233/1635315

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forget to write failure block.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
} 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
}];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have a failure block already, i just didn't add it in here because it was irrelevant! The failure/success blocks only account for fundamental errors.

Comment: Ok, just now checked your comment. Check my comment below your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in your block

```
NSDictionary *headersCollection=[[(NSDictionary *)operation valueForKey:@"response"]valueForKey:@"allHeaderFields"];
NSMutableDictionary *headers=[headersCollection mutableCopy];
headers[@"statusCode"]=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:operation.response.statusCode];
```

and then check the status code value. Headers dictionary will provide you the complete header which is returned. If statuscode is 200 everything is OK else you can show your custom message accordingly with different status code values like 400, 415 etc

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: well u can do anything when u get the header and statuscode. As in the question it is not mentioned how json fails. It can fail in any context. Secondly if you want to pass this header dictionary to some other controller where you are executing the web service call, you can make the success block there and pass the dictionary of headers